# Quartz.Net XML config start-time / end-time

Tags: c#, xml, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to set up a trigger in quartz_jobs.xml that launches a job at 8:05AM and finishes today at 12:10PM from Monday to Friday. The job is not repeated, the job is fetching continuous data.
Any idea how to do that? Can I do that with a simple trigger, as the cron trigger does not have control on the end-time?

I would like something like this, but I do not know the syntax:

```
<start-time>todayT08:05:00.0Z</start-time>
<end-time>todayT12:10:00.0Z</end-time>
```

Find below the code I try which does not work:

```
<job>
  <name>simplejob</name>
  <group>jobGroup1</group>
  <description>jobDesciption1</description>
  <job-type>BigBrother.ScheduledJobs.DataFeedJob, BigBrother</job-type>
  <durable>true</durable>
  <recover>false</recover>
  <job-data-map>
    <entry>
      <key>JobMapDataKey_HistRTD</key>
      <value>RTD</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key>JobMapDataKey_ParamaterFile</key>
      <value>Config\ParametersData_Test.csv</value>
    </entry>
  </job-data-map>
</job>

<trigger>
 <simple>
    <name>SimpleTrigger</name>
    <job-name>simplejob</job-name>
    <job-group>jobGroup1</job-group>
    <!-- It will run from Monday To Friday at 8:05 to 12:10PM-->
     <start-time>2015-04-14T08:05:00.0Z</start-time>
    <end-time>2015-04-14T12:10:00.0Z</end-time>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
  </simple>
</trigger>
```

Comment: You want the job to stop executing at 12:10 pm, even while it's running?

Comment: Yes, I want the job to stop executing at 12:10pm even if it is running.

Comment: A job can only be interrupted programmatically, by implementing the `IInterruptableJob` interface. `<end-time>` means do not repeat job after that time.

Comment: Ok thanks, it makes sense now. I will take a look at IInterruptableJob interface.